VBA Macro for Exact Match Filtering
I have a VBA macro that filters on 6 differents criteria, but I'm encountering an issue where the filter includes partial matches. For example, when I filter for the element 1 "G56", it also includes entries like "G56736". I need the filter to match exactly on the specified characters.
Here is my relevant  code:
     For Each c In Range("ListeCodes")
    If c.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    el1 = c.Offset(0, -6).Value
    el2 = c.Offset(0, -5).Value
    el3 = c.Offset(0, -4).Value
    el4 = c.Offset(0, -3).Value
    el5 = c.Offset(0, -2).Value
    el6 = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Range("CritEl1").Value = el1
    Range("CritEl2").Value = el2
    Range("CritEl3").Value = el3
    Range("CritEl4").Value = el4
    Range("CritEl5").Value = el5
    Range("CritEl6").Value = el6
    Range("CritEl1Verif").Value = el1
    Range("CritEl2Verif").Value = el2
    Range("CritEl3Verif").Value = el3
    Range("CritEl4Verif").Value = el4
    Range("CritEl5Verif").Value = el5
    Range("CritEl6Verif").Value = el6
    Sheets("Base").Select
 Range("A1").Select
 Range("BaseCoda").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
     Range("J1:O2"), Unique:=False
 Application.Goto Reference:="BaseCoda"
 Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 50
 Range("A1").Select
 ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

 Next c

 (Range("BaseCoda").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("J1:O2"), Unique:=False
 Application.Goto Reference:="BaseCoda")

I've tried changing it to ensure an exact match, but it doesn't seem to work:
    Range("CritEl1").Value = "=" & el1
 Range("CritEl2").Value = "=" & el2
 Range("CritEl3").Value = "=" & el3
....

How can I modify my VBA code to filter based strictly on the exact match of the 6 elements?
as explained: the combination of the 6 elements give us a code (that's not that relevant for the VBA code) that's the combination that will filter the data ( see second picture)
Combination:

Data:

Picture 3 :

Thanks in advance for your help!

"G56" is present in the string "G56736" so unless you know what the delimiters are then that will be found. Testing the length of any potential matches for equality to that of your target pattern is one way to disambiguate them.

For exact match: Range("CritEl1").Formula = "=""=" & el1 & """"

Hi, @TimWilliams ! I think this only works with one criteria as I test 6 criteria at the same time it doesn't work but thanks for the help !

@MartinBrown ,the elements can vary from 3 to 7 characters on the different criteria but this changes all the time so I can't really determine the number unfortunately. Or can I determine the number of characters per line? I only want G56 (=3) if G567 (=4) then it would be rejected?
Thanks in advance

Your use of named ranges makes it difficult to know what is going where when you fill the criteria range, and it’s not clear how the range relates to the data table.

@TimWilliams , yes sorry about that : here are some more information:
I have a table with several columns, each serving a specific purpose. Here's a breakdown of what each column represents:
Element 1 to Element 6: These columns contain specific values that, when combined, form a unique code.
Code: This column contains the resulting code from the combination of the six elements. The range of this column in my Excel sheet is named "listecodes".
"base coda" is the table with the 6 elements that I want to filter with

Do the headers in your criteria range match the headers of the first 6 rows of your data table?

And did you test using multiple "exact" criteria?  Pretty sure that works.

@TimWilliams: Do you mean this ?
Range("CritEl1").Formula = "=""=" & el1 & """"
Range("CritEl2").Formula = "=""=" & el2 & """"
Range("CritEl3").Formula = "=""=" & el3 & """"
Range("CritEl4").Formula = "=""=" & el4 & """"
Range("CritEl5").Formula = "=""=" & el5 & """"
Range("CritEl6").Formula = "=""=" & el6 & """"
if so, yes ..it doesn't work

Please edit your question if you have code to add.  It would also be useful to add a small example of what you expect to get as a result of the filter.  As I previously commented, your use of named ranges makes it difficult for us to know how your criteria range is set up and which values end up where in that range, so maybe you can also show a screenshot of the criteria range to assist.

Small example:

This code hides rows 6 and 7:
    Range("A5:E8").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
                                  CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:E2")


Now, I understand why it didn't work. I edited my post so you can see the data I want to filter. In your example, the second row is completely filled. In mine, the columns el-2-3-4-5 or 6 could be blank, but the data I want to filter is always filled. So, when I apply your code, the filter doesn't work. Should I add a condition? To specify that if the column is empty, it should not be considered in the database?

So your problem is no longer on partial matches?  I'm not clear on what the issue is, other than it involves some criteria being blank.  Are you able to share a file which shows the problem?  Or a before/after screenshot and explain exactly why the result is not what you want/expect?

exactly, your code hide as expected the row when my el 1 to el 6 is filled but as I said, the el 1 to el 6 is almost never filled. and so when I applied your code almost everything is not filtered in my databse. I've edited my first post, so you can see with an example ( Picture 3)

In the example, the row will not be filtered because the el 4 is not filled.

What do you expect to happen in the above example if (eg) there's no criteria for "Col04".  It just gets ignored and filtering happens based on the other 5 values.  Should something else happen?

Basically, I filter tens of thousands of accounting lines. The lines that are filtered are validated, the others are "rejected".
Validated means that it meets the set criteria. In the example, the line should be validated because it meets the set criteria, even though it has no requirement in "Col4". With the exact match, the line is "obviously" not filtered (and therefore rejected). Do I need to add a condition that, if there is no requirement in a column, it is ignored?

"Filtered" means the line is hidden, or not hidden?  If there's no criteria for Col4 then that column is not used in the filtering.  I'm still not clear exactly what the problem is.  Please edit your question to show exactly what's happening, and explain exactly how that's different from what you expect.  A small example of pre-filter, post-filter, and expected post-filter would really help here.

...I can't tell what your "picture 3" is intended to show.
